# Dropdown menu close when user click anywhere on body or outside dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/runuv3ps/1/)

Html

```
<input type="text" class="js-search" name="" value="">

<div class="category-list">
  <i class="icon-close"></i>
  <div class="select-column">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="category-select" href="#">Test1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="category-select" href="#">Test2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="category-select" href="#">Test3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
var search = $('.js-search');
var menu = $('.category-list');
var close = $('.icon-close');
var category = $('.category-select');
 search.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.fadeIn("normal", function() {
       $(this).show();
         $(document).click(function(e){
            menu.fadeOut("normal", function() {
           $(this).hide();
});
     });
    close.on('click', function(){
      menu.fadeOut("normal", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        });
    });
    category.on('click', function(){
      var el = $(this);
      search.val("");
      menu.fadeOut("normal", function(){
        $(this).hide();
      });

      search.val(el.text());
    });
 });
 });
$('body').click(function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).closest(menu).length === 0) {
        menu.fadeOut("normal", function() {
          $(this).hide();
          });
     }
 });
```

Managed to show or hide the dropdown menu also with fade classes. Only the problem left is that the menu will continue opening and closing everytime click on input field. Looked answer up on google, but in vain. Might have overlooked something missing. Or the code is not right.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Adding `document` click event handler (and two more handlers for `.icon-close` and `.category-select`) on every `.js-search` click is definitely bad idea. Moreover, what is the point to use `$(this).show();` on `.fadeIn()` completeness?

Comment: on input field you want to show the drop down right?

Comment: @Regent: yah, what's the use of unused code, so that it can be done with show/hide

Comment: @joe [this simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/runuv3ps/3/) is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @AmolTate - yes when click on input the dropdown will show in fade

Comment: @Regent - i see what you mean. and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified code without "`click` handlers in `click` handlers". The whole idea is to open dropdown menu on `<input>` click, to put selected `<a>` text into `<input>` and to hide dropdown on click anywhere except `<input>`:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/runuv3ps/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var search = $('.js-search');
    var menu = $('.category-list');
    var category = $('.category-select');

    search.on('click', function()
    {
        menu.fadeIn("normal");
        return false;
    });

    category.on('click', function()
    {
        search.val($(this).text());
    });

    $(document).on('click', function()
    {
        menu.fadeOut("normal");
    });
});
```